# Access VBA To Join A Text To Numeric

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am attempting to write a Select statement against two tables - unfortunately I am not able to change DDL for either table.

This is the select statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT unitid 
FROM [piece1] 
WHERE [piece1].[unitid] IN (
                             SELECT DISTINCT [department id] 
                             FROM [vendorspreadsheet] 
                             WHERE [vendorspreadsheet].[department id] IS NOT NULL)
```

Now the issue is that `piece1.unitid` is a short text data type but `vendorspreadsheet.[department id]` is a numeric data type.

What would be the appropriate way to alter this syntax so that the query will execute succesfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
WHERE cdbl([piece1].[unitid]) IN
```

But it may slow down performance. Better solution would be convert piece1.unitid to numeric. 
Of course, I assumed that piece1.unitid contains number stored as literals.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WHERE Clng([piece1].[unitid]) IN
```